# bash script: how to cope with the different cp behaviors?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

Among the tons of cp questions I have not found anything about this difference in behaviour (tested on Ubuntu 18.04). Sorry for the lost post, but the setting is a bit complex.

**Case 1:** This is the expected behaviour

Given the following folder

```
 source                     
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
```

after running this script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cp -r source/ target/
```

I do get this result

```
 source                     # same as above, plus a copy in "target"
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
 target  
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
```

**Case 2:** Using the same script, source folder exists and is empty in the target folder

Here there is one additional, empty folder 
     source
        file1.cpp
        file2.cpp
     target
        source

and run the same script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cp -r source/ target/
```

which gives me a different, undesired result

```
 source                     # same as above, plus a copy in "target"
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
 target  
    source
       file1.cpp
       file2.cpp
```

**Normal Solution for Case1 and Case2**

```
 cp -r source/  target/       # works only for Case 1
 cp -r source/* target/       # works only for Case 2
```

Used in the wrong case, one will cause an error, the other yield the wrong result which can be very confusing. This means for each copy action I must check if the target folder exists and use a different command. That is very cumbersome but I am not aware of a more simple solution.

**Unresolved situation for Case2**

However, the problem I have is this one: When I use variables for the source and target my script looks like this

```
 #!/bin/bash
 SOURCE="source"
 TARGET="target"

 if [ -d "$TARGET" ]; then
   cp -r $SOURCE $TARGET     
 else
   cp -r $SOURCE/* $TARGET     # note "$SOURCE/*" would fail.
 fi
```

and I have a $SOURCE path with spaces.

SOURCE="source code"

Since I can not use quotations for the source variable, this causes two 'directory not found errors'.

How can I solve this for Case2?

**EDIT**

To clarify the problem a bit more. This

```
SOURCE="source" 
cp -r "$SOURCE/*" $TARGET
```

fails with the error "cannot stat source/*: No such file or directory". I think that means that bash can not replace the /* with the file list and cp gets this as a file literal. A file or folder with the name "source/*" obviously does not exist. But maybe I am thinking too simple and what bash does is different.

Comment: To treat paths with spaces your script should double quote variable accesses.

Comment: That is the problem I described. When you do it the CP command will fail. Maybe I add that explicitly.

Comment: Added an explanation why Quotes do not solve the problem, but are part of the problem. Hope it clarifies that a bit more. Thanks

Comment: Ok I think I understood the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your main issue concerns the `cp` command there is also something I would like to say about your try. So lets get it step by step.

### Issue 1: `cp` behaviour

The `cp` command behaves differently when the target folder contains a folder with the same name than the source folder. This behaviour is intended but can be avoided using the `-T` option according to [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp).

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94831/cp-no-target-directory-explained) you can find an extended explanation of the `-T` option.

Thus, you can just execute:

```
cp -rT source/ target/
```

### Issue 2: Paths containing spaces

In your try you mention issues when handling paths using spaces. Although with the previous solution you don't need a custom script, I want to highlight that variables with paths containing spaces require all accesses to be double-quoted. The variable content must be double-quoted, not the star (since you want the globstar to expand, not to be taken literally). Hence, your previous script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=${1:-"source"}
TARGET=${2:-"target"}

if [ -d "$TARGET" ]; then
  cp -r "$SOURCE" "$TARGET"     
else
  cp -r "$SOURCE"/* "$TARGET"    # note "$SOURCE/*" would fail.
fi
```

Comment: Perfect. Not seeing the forest because of too many trees :-). The quotes only to a part solved it. However, I do not understand the relevant of the T-option. In both cases I wanted to copy the *content* of the source and not care if the target folder exists or not. If -T is about what the target folder contains, that is not the use case. In one case it does not exist at all and in the other it was empty.

Comment: @CatMan I'd say that the -T option is exactly what you are looking for. When the target folder contains an empty src folder, it copies it normally. Maybe I am not making myself clear and the man doesn't help either so I'd suggest you to try it out and check if it has the behaviour that you were expecting.

Comment: @CatMan Also, remember to accept the answer if this solved your issue :)

Comment: You are right. Seeing an example helps. Thats why I can not understand why man files so rarely have examples.. You are correct. The -T option eliminates the need for two version, as it brings the same results for both cases. But I must admit that I can neither from the man nor from your description understand what it does or when to use it. If you happen to have some link to explained examples for the T-option, that would actually be the correct answer to the underlying problem of the issue.

Comment: @CatMan Glad to hear that. I have been looking for more information about the -T option and found a quite descriptive post on Unix&Linux StackExchange. I have updated the answer providing the link. Hope it is useful.

Comment: Perfect. Thats a very good article, so now I understood it. I think this completes the answer perfectly. So if I ever come across the issue again, I can rest assured to find the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe us CP for individual files and wse rsync for directories ?

```
rsync -vazh /source /destination
```

(includes 'source' dir)

```
rsync -vazh /source/ /destination
```

(does not include 'source' dir)

Comment: well, thats what I also ended up with. But this would not have helped me to understand the problem with cp..

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r --copy-contents source/ target/
```

--copy-contents means copy only the content of source

for understand better that happend in your case test this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
```

you can do some like that if this pwd  write different places:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd SOURCE_PARENT
cp -r --copy-contents source/ target/
```

if you have spaces in the target or source name  have this in mind
cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY

```
target name <= "target realTarget"
cp -r source target realTarget
```

cp -r *source target* **realTarget**  believe that  you want copy source & target in realTarget it don't understand that "target realTarget" is a full name if you need copy it you have to use the double quotation marks in the comandad

```
cp -r source "target realTarget"
```

cp -r *source* **"target realTarget"** now "target realTarget" is taken as folder name

with source happend the same use the double quotation marks and you will solve the problem

->with your extra: (escape the quotes using `\`)

```
SOURCE="\"source realsource\"" 
cp -rT --copy-contents $SOURCE $TARGET
```

-T, --no-target-directory
treat DEST as a normal file

Comment: When I am using cp -r --copy-contents $SOURCE $TARGET I still get the 2 cases as described. With 'target' exists I see case 2 and if not I see case 1.

Comment: Right, with your update it works, thanks. However, for me it also worked without the --copy-contents option, though.

Comment: Use that you prefer, is the good part of the computing that have a lot of forms that solve the same problem